# What is the difference between widget post() vs. handler post()?

Tags: android

I have a WebView which I initialize with loadUrl in AsyncTask.doInBackground. I initialize it like below :

```
webView.post(new Runnable() {               
    @Override
    public void run() {
        webView.loadUrl(authURL);                   
    }
});
```

AsyncTask is executed as last in Activity.onCreate(), the problem is that most of the time webpage does not get loaded, I see white screen. If I replace webView with handler then all is ok. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why are you doing this in `doInBackground()` if it needs to run on the UI thread anyway?

The difference between `Hander.post()` and `View.post()` is that `Handler` will run your code 
on the thread the `Handler` instance was created on (which is not necessarily the UI thread), while `View` will always run it on the UI thread (because views are bound to it).

Comment: Before calling loadUrl I need to retrieve this url from the server. I know that by introducing some more code complexity I could do it in onPostExecute. I am starting to think that the whole problem is related to what docs says for View.post(): "This method can be invoked from outside of the UI thread only when this View is attached to a window.", but I donts see how this can happen in my case.

Comment: Not sure about how your views are attached, but you should definitely be calling this from `onPostExecute()`. The added complexity will be returning a list of URLs or saving them into a field. Additionally, you might want to call this from `onStart()` where the view creation is guaranteed to have finished.